# How to receive a daily notification at a specific time in Android with WorkManager and OneTimeWorkRequest?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-workmanager, periodicity

**My goal**

Receive a single notification every 8 am when my switch is activated

**Current result**

-I receive a notification each time I launch the app if I first activated the switch

-I also receive notifications without launching the app at any time

-In addition, I receive several notifications in one day

**what I did (my code)**

-NotificationActivity (part of the onCreate)

```
 private void onClickSwitch() {
        aSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                retrieveKeyWord();
                retrieveCategories();

                keywordPref = mPreferences.getString(PREF_KEYWORD, null);
                categoriesPref = mPreferences.getString(PREF_CATEGORIES, null);

                mPreferences.edit().putString(PREF_KEYWORD, keyword).apply();
                mPreferences.edit().putString(PREF_CATEGORIES, categories).apply();

                Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                dueDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
                dueDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                dueDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                if(dueDate.before(currentDate)) {
                    dueDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
                }

                long timeDiff =  dueDate.getTimeInMillis() - currentDate.getTimeInMillis();


                Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build();

                OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class).setInitialDelay(timeDiff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .addTag("TAG_OUTPUT").build();


                WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);

            }
        });
    }
```

-NotificationActivity -> Layout

[image: layout]

-NotificationWorker

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {

    private SharedPreferences mPreference;
    private String keyword;
    private String categories;
    private ResultModel resultModel;
    private ResultContract.Model.OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener;
    private int numberOfArticle;


    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        mPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(NotificationActivity.PREFERENCE_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);

        keyword = mPreference.getString(NotificationActivity.PREF_KEYWORD, null);
        categories = mPreference.getString(NotificationActivity.PREF_CATEGORIES, null);


        resultModel = new ResultModel();

        numberOfArticle = resultModel.getResultListWithoutDate(onFinishedListener, 1, keyword, categories);

        displayNotification(keyword);

        return Result.success();
    }


    private void displayNotification(String keyword) {

     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("simplifiedcoding", "simplifiedcoding", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
         assert notificationManager != null;
         notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
     }

     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "simplifiedcoding")
             .setContentTitle("Articles sur : " + keyword)
             .setContentText("Nombre d'articles trouvés : " + numberOfArticle)
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    }
}
```

Tell me if you need more information, thanks to who will help me

Comment: `WorkManger` doesn't work periodically on exact time slot. You can use `Alarm Manager` instead

Comment: I have similar and maybe the same problem as you have. I hope you have solved this and you can give some input. My app fires off notifications randomly, fires them of when activity is created, and worst of all which bugs me the most is that sends notifications in bunches

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with 3 ways.

First:

User Alarm Manager and put that in a IF that check activity is alive so it will work if your app opened.you can take more Information from google docs link below:

[AlarmManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Second :

u can Use a Timer with Task to create a notification, you can check if activity alive again but better use is that to create Timer on Foreground service.

Third:

Use PushNotification from server when even u need it.
the Docs and information if link below:

[Push Notification - One Signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)

Note:

I recommend You to use third way for your issue.

Have good Coding and dont forget vote me ;)

Comment: Is not there a solution without changing my code too much?

Comment: Can you further develop for your third way?

Comment: for third way, there is a clear doc on one signal site. Yes i can.if u dont want change use first way

Comment: dont forget check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As your goal is to receive notification everyday at 8 am, I would recommend you to use 
[PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) rather than using [OneTimeWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest).

**PeriodicWorkRequest (From Documentation):**

> A WorkRequest for repeating work. This work executes multiple times
>   until it is  cancelled, with the first execution happening immediately
>   or as soon as the given  Constraints are met. The next execution will
>   happen during the period interval; note  that execution may be delayed
>   because WorkManager is subject to OS battery  optimizations, such as
>   doze mode.

**OneTimeWorkRequest (From Documentation):**

> A WorkRequest for non-repeating work.

Comment: the problem with periodicWorkRequest is that it's interval, so it's not as accurate as setting a specific time

Answer (score 1):

This does work when using PeriodicWorkRequest. The trick is to use `setInitialDelay`.

```kotlin
fun Context.enqueueReminderWorker(
  localTime: LocalTime
) {
  val now = ZonedDateTime.now()
  val trigger = now.with(localTime)
  val realTrigger = when {
    trigger <= now -> trigger.plusDays(1)
    else -> trigger
  }

  val initialDelay = maxOf(1, realTrigger.toEpochSecond() - Instant.now().epochSecond)

  val notificationWork = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker::class.java, 1, DAYS)
    .setInitialDelay(initialDelay, SECONDS)
    .build()

  WorkManager.getInstance(this)
    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(NotificationWorker.TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, notificationWork)
}
```

I'll have a `PeriodicWorkRequest` with an interval of 1 Day (24 hours) and using `setInitialDelay` I can shift the starting time from now to my desired starting point e.g. 8 AM in the morning. `NotificationWorker` is as simple as:

```kotlin
class NotificationWorker(
  context: Context,
  workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
  override fun doWork(): Result {
    // Your logic to show a notification.

    return Result.success()
  }

  companion object {
    const val TAG = "DailyReminder"
  }
}
```

I'm calling `Context#enqueueReminderWorker` in `Application#onCreate` and when the user changes the preferred time.